# I need to get the duplicate data in column parenthesis

Tags: arrays, json, oracle

```
UPDATE tab s
SET s.DATA = json_transform(DATA, REPLACE '$.dataFilterDefn.columns[1]' = (SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON FORMAT JSON RETURNING CLOB) 
FROM 
    (SELECT JSON 
     FROM 
         (SELECT j.json || ',' || JSON AS json
          FROM tab d
          CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(d.tab, '$.dataFilterDefn.columns[1]' COLUMNS(json CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$')) j
          WHERE d.UID = 252))));
```

The data look like this:

```
"columns":[
        {
           "label":"Subcategory",
           "aggFn":"NONE",
           "datasetId":"ADVENTURE_WORKS",
           "fieldName":"SUB_CAT",
           "id":"FILTER-1"
        }
      ]
```

My expectation:

```
"columns":[
        {
           "label":"Subcategory",
           "aggFn":"NONE",
           "datasetId":"ADVENTURE_WORKS",
           "fieldName":"SUB_CAT",
           "id":"FILTER-1"
        },
        {
           "label":"Subcategory",
           "aggFn":"NONE",
           "datasetId":"ADVENTURE_WORKS",
           "fieldName":"SUB_CAT",
           "id":"FILTER-1"
        }
       ]
```

I want the columns data should duplicate.The columns value will be different.It"ll not be the same. I need to update the column values dynamically..It should not be hardcoded. How can I achieve this in json using Oracle version 19c?

Answer (score 0):

Using `json_transform` you can `append` items to an array. Using `json_query` you can extract the first element of the array.

So you can do something like this:

```
with rws as (
  select '{ "columns":[
        {
           "label":"Subcategory",
           "aggFn":"NONE",
           "datasetId":"ADVENTURE_WORKS",
           "fieldName":"SUB_CAT",
           "id":"ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
        }
      ] }' jdata 
  from    dual
)
  select json_transform (
           jdata,
           append '$.columns' = json_query ( jdata, '$.columns[0]' )
           returning varchar2 pretty
         )
  from   rws r;
  
{
  "columns" :
  [
    {
      "label" : "Subcategory",
      "aggFn" : "NONE",
      "datasetId" : "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
      "fieldName" : "SUB_CAT",
      "id" : "ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
    },
    {
      "label" : "Subcategory",
      "aggFn" : "NONE",
      "datasetId" : "ADVENTURE_WORKS",
      "fieldName" : "SUB_CAT",
      "id" : "ART-DATA-FILTER-1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that `json_transform` was only added in a recent release update, so ensure your 19c version is fully patched and up-to-date.